# Linux rename with a variable character?

Tags: linux, rename, batch-rename

I have a list of files eg.

```
page-1.htm
page-2.htm
page-32.htm
```

How do I use rename to be like this:

```
page-01.htm
page-02.htm
page-32.htm
```

I am new to this and having trouble understanding the examples online. 
I want to do something like the following where the ? is a variable character:

```
rename 's/page-?.htm$/page-0?.htm/' *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` mean "any character".

So, your `page-1.htm` will be rename because it's match with pattern `page-?.htm` but `page-32.htm` don't

for your problem, you can use `find | replace` method, like this:

```
find -name 'page_?.htm' | rename 's/page_/page_0/'
```

I know it's doesn't what you really want, but it's temp solution